# How to bind data to JSON file based on @para-id

Tags: c#, json, data-binding, parameter-passing

In my project client send me this JSON string.

```
{
  "onlineRequest": {
    "CustomerCode": "AB432A",
    "MobileNumber": "75484568",
    "ProductNo": "100",
    "JsonFile": {
      "evaluation": {
        "number": [
          {
            "@para-id": "5656",
            "@new-code": "",
            "@text": "Hello America"
          },
          {
            "@para-id": "3302",
            "@new-code": "100",
            "@text": "Hello Japan"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This JSON contains inner JSON called `JsonFile`. Now I need to set the values to this JSON file as follows.

**`if @para-id = 5656, then @new-code = "0000"
if @para-id = 3302, then @new-code = "1111"`**

Expected Output:

```
{
  "onlineRequest": {
    "CustomerCode": "AB432A",
    "MobileNumber": "75484568",
    "ProductNo": "100",
    "JsonFile": {
      "evaluation": {
        "number": [
          {
            "@para-id": "5656",
            "@new-code": "0000",
            "@text": "Hello America"
          },
          {
            "@para-id": "3302",
            "@new-code": "1111",
            "@text": "Hello Japan"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be easily done with [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/):

```
var source = @"{
  ""onlineRequest"": {
    ""CustomerCode"": ""AB432A"",
    ""MobileNumber"": ""75484568"",
    ""ProductNo"": ""100"",
    ""JsonFile"": {
      ""evaluation"": {
        ""number"": [
          {
            ""@para-id"": ""5656"",
            ""@new-code"": """",
            ""@text"": ""Hello America""
          },
          {
            ""@para-id"": ""3302"",
            ""@new-code"": ""100"",
            ""@text"": ""Hello Japan""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}";
var json = JToken.Parse(source);
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["5656"] = "0000",
    ["3302"] = "1000",
};

foreach (var number in json.SelectToken("onlineRequest.JsonFile.evaluation.number").ToArray())
{
    var id = (string)number["@para-id"];
    if (id != null && dict.TryGetValue(id, out var code))
    {
        number["@new-code"] = code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But can you please tell me after doing this, how can I print the expected output (mentioned in the question). I don't have an idea to that. can you please give me a sample code to do that. please

Comment: @Adam `json.ToString()` will return you the string you need. You can then `Console.WriteLine(json.ToString())`

Comment: Oops !!! Thanks in advance. you saved my whole day. I have another JSON sir, I'll ask that tomorrow. please help me ;)

Comment: sir I have another question. please help me to solve this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559067/how-to-bind-values-to-json-file-based-on-values-in-json