# How to bind values to JSON file based on values in JSON?

Tags: c#, json, data-binding, parameters

My client sends me a JSON file which as follows:

```
{  
   "onlineRequest":{  
      "MobileNumber":"75484568",
      "ProductNo":"100",
      "JsonFile":{  
         "evaluation":{  
            "number":[  
               {  
                  "@para-id":"5656",
                  "@new-code":"",
                  "@text":"Hello America"
               },
               {  
                  "@para-id":"3302",
                  "@new-code":"100",
                  "@text":"Hello UK"
               }
            ],
            "dropdown":[  
               {  
                  "@para-id":"2572",
                  "@new-code":"",
                  "@text":"This is first dropdown",
                  "option":[  
                     {  
                        "@text":"Option 1",
                        "@value":"0"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "@para-id":"2584",
                  "@new-code":"",
                  "@text":"This is second dropdown",
                  "option":[  
                     {  
                        "@text":"Excellent",
                        "@value":"0"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "@para-id":"2575",
                  "@new-code":"",
                  "@text":"This is third dropdown",
                  "option":[  
                     {  
                        "@text":"Available",
                        "@value":"0"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now I need to set the values to this JSON file based on its some parameters.This JSON file consists with Inner JSON called `JsonFile`. In the `number` part, If

> if @para-id = 5656, then @new-code = "0000"
>
> if @para-id = 3302, then @new-code = "1111"
>
> if @para-id = 3585, then @new-code = "2222"

To achieve this, My C# code as follows, `source` means JSON string.

```
var json = JToken.Parse(source);
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["5656"] = "0000",
    ["3302"] = "1000",
};

foreach (var number in json.SelectToken("onlineRequest.JsonFile.evaluation.number").ToArray())
{
    var id = (string)number["@para-id"];
    if (id != null && dict.TryGetValue(id, out var code))
    {
        number["@new-code"] = code;
    }
}
```

This above code works fine for `number` part. But the problem is in the  `dropdown` part. now I need to set values to `dropdown` part in the JSON as follows

**UPDATED:**

> if @para-id = 2572,
>    if there @value = 0 then @new-code = 50,
>
> if there @value = 1 then @new-code = 100,
>
> if there @value = 2 then @new-code = 150,
>
> if @para-id = 2584,
>     if there @value = 0 then @new-code = 10,
>
> if there @value = 1 then @new-code = 20,
>
> if there @value = 2 then @new-code = 30,
>
> if @para-id = 2575,
>    in there @value = 0 then @new-code = 40,
>
> in there @value = 1 then @new-code = 80,

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
"dropdown":[  
   {  
      "@para-id":"2572",
      "@new-code":"50",
      "@text":"This is first dropdown",
      "option":[  
         {  
            "@text":"Option 1",
            "@value":"0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "@para-id":"2584",
      "@new-code":"30",
      "@text":"This is second dropdown",
      "option":[  
         {  
            "@text":"Excellent",
            "@value":"2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "@para-id":"2575",
      "@new-code":"80",
      "@text":"This is third dropdown",
      "option":[  
         {  
            "@text":"Not Available",
            "@value":"1"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I'm so confused with this, So please help me to solve this problem. How can I set values as above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 please help me sir :)

Comment: What do you mean by "there is @value = x then @new-code = y", when there is  multiple `@value`s for one only `@new-value` in dropdown? Give an example of before & after transform.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Hello sir, I updated question. I received JSON as previously, But I edit JSON string as above. If `@para-id = 2572` , In there `@value = 0   @new-code should be 50 ,if @value = 1   @new-code should be 100 if @value = 2   @new-code should be 150 `  like that.  same thing for other @para-id's

Comment: @Xiaoy312 please help me sir :( I posted expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same idea as the existing, except you would need to use a custom function (`Func<int, int>` in this case) to compute the new value this time:

```
var dropdownNewCodeMapping = new Dictionary<int, Func<int, int>>
{
    [2572] = x => (x + 1) * 50,
    [2584] = x => (x + 1) * 10,
    [2575] = x => (x + 1) * 40,
};
foreach (var dropdown in json.SelectToken("onlineRequest.JsonFile.evaluation.dropdown").ToArray())
{
    var id = (int)dropdown["@para-id"];
    var value = (int)dropdown.SelectToken("option[0].@value");

    dropdown["@new-code"] = dropdownNewCodeMapping[id](value).ToString();
}
```